# Replace method that adds an incrementing number to a repeated string

Tags: javascript, node.js, methods, replace

I have a document with a bunch of `<a id="r"></a>` tags, and want to add an incrementing number to each, so, `<a id="r1"></a>`... `<a id="r2"></a>`, etc. The loop that I currently have, doesn't seem to work.

```
function(doc) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= doc.length; i++) {
      var number = 1;
      return doc.replace(/<a id=""><\/a>/, '<a id="page' + number + '"></a>');
      number += 1
};},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want to loop. Try doing a global regex with the incrementing number in the replace pattern:

```
function(doc) {
    var number = 1;
    return doc.replace(/(<a\s+[^>]*id="r)("[^>]*>[^<]*<\/a>)/gi, function(m, a, b) {
        return a + (number++) + b;
    });
};
```

This looks for any `<A>` tags with `id="r"`, keeps their content and attributes the same, but changes the `r` to `r1`, `r2`, `r#`. Is this what you want?

Comment: So given this, if I wanted to iterate over multiple .xhtml files, is there a way to save the end number and have it start again at that number for the next file?

Comment: Then you would move `number` outside this function. That way it won't reset every time it's called. Let me know if you need help with this.

Comment: Thank you, so, so much for explaining this. So simple, yet so oblivious to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you `return` inside the loop, it won't iterate multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `var number = 1;` inside the loop. You already have an integer with `i`, so use `+ i +`, and you're returning inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

try declaring `number` outside of the loop.

```
function(doc) {
  var number=1;
  for (var i=1;i<=doc.length;i++) {
    return doc.replace(/<a id=""><\/a>/,'<a id=\"page'+number+'\"></a>');
    number+=1;
  }
},
```